# android-maps-utils for Java?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Is there something like [Google Maps Android API utility library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) (for Android) but for Java?

In specific, we need to implement [the `containsLocation` method](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#containsLocation-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-), but for a Java web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I successfully used the following library on web applications.

https://github.com/sromku/polygon-contains-point

```
Polygon polygon = Polygon.Builder()
    .addVertex(new Point(1, 3))
    .addVertex(new Point(2, 8))
    .addVertex(new Point(5, 4))
    .addVertex(new Point(5, 9))
    .addVertex(new Point(7, 5))
    .addVertex(new Point(6, 1))
    .addVertex(new Point(3, 1))
    .build();

Point point = new Point(4.5f, 7);
boolean contains = polygon.contains(point);
```

Comment: i'm creating a real use case to validate if this utility works for GPS positions. i'll comment what happened... if successful i'll mark this answer as solution, thanks in advance.